# How to set position of a Map on WebPage

Tags: openlayers-2

I am using OpenLayers to create a map and I am using:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map')
```

to create the map layer. But the map appears somewhere down in the web page. How can I tell where the map is to be placed on the page. I read the OpenLayers documentation and found that there are some attributes that can be defined with the above map variable like:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
    maxResolution: 2
    });
```

But I am not able to see any difference in position of the map. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I think it would be great if you can post a link to a picture of the map and if possible, the source code of your HTML file.

Comment: The position of the map is set by css on your page, ie, you have a div called map, which you place either using absolute positioning or relative. The javascript code above has nothing to do with where the map appears on the page.